# Creating mock object within python unittest

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, python-unittest

I am completely new to unittest in Python, so sorry if this is a noob question.

I have a Customer class:

```
class Customer(object):

    def __init__(self, name, clubMember, taxExempt):
        self.name = name
        self.clubMember = clubMember
        self.taxExempt = taxExempt

    def isClubMember(self):
        if (self.clubMember == True):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def isTaxExempt(self):
        if (self.taxExempt == True):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

And I want to test it with a kind of mock Customer with:

```
import unittest
import Customer 

class TestCustomer(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.customer = Customer("John Doe", True, False)

    def test_customer_member_status(self):
        self.assertTrue(self.customer.isClubMember(), 'incorrect member status')

    def test_customer_tax_exemption(self):
        self.assertFalse(self.customer.isTaxExempt(), 'incorrect tax status')

    def tearDown(self):
        self.customer.dispose()
```

However, I receive the following error:

```
self.customer = Customer("John Doe", True, False)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I've tried to search many different websites, but I cannot find the correct format to create the mock Customer. In addition, I'm not sure how to create multiple mock Customers to test another example, such as Customer("Jane Doe", False, True) etc.

Comment: Is your `Customer` class defined in `Customer.py` by any chance? If so you need to change the import in your test file to be `from Customer import Customer`

Comment: Can you show your directory structure? Is your file containing the `Customer` class called `Customer.py`? If it is, you probably want `from Customer import Customer`. As a note though, this isn't really about Mocking! You definitely *don't* want to mock `Customer` as that's the thing you're testing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your module name is also `Customer` and when you are doing `import Customer` , it is importing the module and not the class.

Do this instead

```
from Customer import Customer
```

in test moudle.